# I came across a segmentation fault when I accessed a correct memory when swap two strings

Tags: c++, string, multidimensional-array, swap, c-strings

I wrote a swap funtion to swap two c'style strings in cpp,before the swap operation.

I can cout the first line of a 2 dimension string s[2][27] correctly,but i swaped s[0] with s[1], I tried to cout s[0] and the compiler gave me a segmentation fault.

```cpp
void swap1(char *a, char *b)
{
    char *temp;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (a[i] != '\0')
    {
        temp[j] = a[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    temp[j] = '\0';
    i = 0, j = 0;
    while (b[i] != '\0')
    {
        a[j] = b[i];
        i++, j++;
    }
    a[j] = '\0';
    i = 0, j = 0;
    while (temp[i] != '\0')
    {
        b[j] = temp[i];
        i++, j++;
    }
    b[j] = '\0';
}
int main()
{
    char s[2][27] = {"wangzhehan", "cuisibo"};
    // const char s[2][10]={"111","222"};
    cout << s[0] << endl;//s[0] can be printed correctly

    swap1(s[0], s[1]);

    cout << s[0];//the compiler showed a segmentation fault here
```

the expected result is
wangzhehan
cuisibo
but in fact the result is
wangzhehan

then the compiler showed"Exception has occurred.
Segmentation fault"
or,is there a better way to swap two string using no standard library function?

Comment: `temp[j]`: You never assigned a value to the pointer `temp`, so this is undefined behavior.

Comment: `temp[j]` is never a valid memory in your code.

Comment: I meant to swap data in string.but what's the exact meaning of swapping string?

Comment: So should I write char temp[27] instead of char *temp?

Comment: @OliverShang If you know that the strings are never longer than that, that would be fine.

Comment: yes temp[27] will statically allocate memory at temp and handle freeing the memory for you when it goes out of scope, or dynamically allocate memory at temp with `char* temp = new char[27];`, and dont forget to delete the memory at the end of the function with `delete[] temp` if you use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Do I have to `delete[] temp`after using `char* temp = new char[27]`? even if the memory is enough for me?

Comment: it will still work properly, but every time the function is called, it will allocate 27 more characters, and it will never be freed, so if you ran the function in a loop, you would eventually run out of memory and the program would crash.

Comment: by the way: _//the compiler showed a segmentation fault here_ no: this is a runtime error, not a compile time one: with "compiler error" we mean an error occouring at compile time, which forbid to complete the compilation and therefore to create an executable file.

Comment: So unlike the formal parameter,it won't be freed automaticlly when the function swap () ends?

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
   char *temp;
[...]
        temp[j] = a[i];
```

stores `a[i]` at whatever address is on stack at the moment (understand to non allocated memory). This will crash. If you need to swap something to a temporary, first allocate your temporary to the size of the minimum string's length.

Please notice that your code is a very bad idea.

The function signature expects two pointer to a char array. It does not say what is the array length. Provided the string will not be the same length, you can't swap the string safely (since the array size for the second parameter can be shorter than the first parameter's array size).

If you *really* want to reinvent the wheel, you'd do something like this:

```
void swap(char *& s1, char *& s2) { char * tmp = s2; s2 = s1; s1 = tmp; }
int main()
{
    char * s[2] = {"wangzhehan", "cuisibo"};
    cout << s[0] << endl;//s[0] can be printed correctly

    swap(s[0], s[1]);

    cout << s[0];
```

Comment: I know the approch to swap two strings is a pretty bad one.What is the better approach?

Comment: Note that your `swap` swaps pointers to strings, not the strings themselves.

Comment: From the usage case given, swapping the pointer is the most efficient things to do (avoid allocation/deletion/memory copy)

Answer (score 1):

When swapping the two strings, you don't need to store a temporary string as a whole.
(or you will have to rely on dynamic allocation)

In your code you declare `char *temp;` and right after you use `temp[j]` but this temporary string is not allocated (the pointer points towards anything).

I won't give here the complete solution, since it looks like an exercise, but only
this suggestion.
Use a single loop, in which you place `a[i]` in a temporary `char` (not `char *`),
then move `b[i]` to `a[i]` and finally move the temporary `char` to `b[i]`.
(you will have to take care of the length of the two strings when swapping the characters)

Answer (score 1):

You did not allocate memory where you are going temporary to copy strings. The pointer `temp` is not initialized.

```
char *temp;
```

So the function invokes undefined behavior.

The function can be written simpler if to use standard C string functions.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

void swap1( char *a, char *b )
{
    size_t n = std::max( strlen( a ), strlen( b ) ) + 1;

    char *temp = new char[n];

    std::strcpy( temp, a );
    std::strcpy( a, b );
    std::strcpy( b, temp );

    delete [] temp;
}    

int main() 
{
    char s[2][27] = {"wangzhehan", "cuisibo"};

    std::cout << s[0] << '\n';

    swap1( s[0], s[1] );

    std::cout << s[0] << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
wangzhehan
cuisibo
```

If you is not allowed to use standard string functions and must to use only loops then the function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>

void swap1( char *a, char *b )
{
    size_t n1 = 0;

    while( a[n1] != '\0' ) ++n1;

    size_t n2 = 0;

    while ( b[n2] != '\0' ) ++n2;

    size_t n = n1 < n2 ? n2 : n1;

    char *temp = new char[n + 1];

    for ( size_t i = 0; ( temp[i] = a[i] ) != '\0'; ++i );
    for ( size_t i = 0; ( a[i] = b[i] ) != '\0'; ++i );
    for ( size_t i = 0; ( b[i] = temp[i] ) != '\0'; ++i );

    delete [] temp;
}    

int main() 
{
    char s[2][27] = {"wangzhehan", "cuisibo"};

    std::cout << s[0] << '\n';

    swap1( s[0], s[1] );

    std::cout << s[0] << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

Again the function output is

```
wangzhehan
cuisibo
```

And at last the most simplest way is to declare the function as a template function. In this case you need not to allocate memory dynamically.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
void swap1( char ( &a )[N], char ( &b )[N] )
{
    char temp[N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; ( temp[i] = a[i] ) != '\0'; ++i );
    for ( size_t i = 0; ( a[i] = b[i] )    != '\0'; ++i );
    for ( size_t i = 0; ( b[i] = temp[i] ) != '\0'; ++i );
}    

int main() 
{
    char s[2][27] = {"wangzhehan", "cuisibo"};

    std::cout << s[0] << '\n';

    swap1( s[0], s[1] );

    std::cout << s[0] << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really think it's a good idea to swap two strings of potentially different lengths that way?

Comment: @Henrik I take into account the approach of the beginner.

Comment: You dealared a varible n,the type of n is size_t??

Comment: @OliverShang Yes the type of variables n, n1, n2 is size_t. And you should use this type though if you like you can it substitute for the type int.

Comment: You should qualify `size_t` with `std::size_t` as well and I think `<iostream>` is not guaranteed to introduce it. @OliverShang `size_t` is an unsigned integer type that represent the size of arrays and other stuff, so it is the correct type to use here, but most of the time other integer types will be fine too (especially if you are limited to a small number of characters as here anyway)

Comment: @uneven_mark There is no need to do this as the header iostream is included.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know that it is fine in practice, but I was wondering whether `<iostream>` actually *needs* to introduce `size_t`. I am pretty sure it doesn't *need* to introduce it into global namespace, though.

Comment: @uneven_mark size_t is a standard C type that is placed in the global namespace.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You may be right, I will have another look myself and ask a question if it is unclear.